# C++ Boost Test Library cpp won't compile

Tags: c++, testing, boost

I'm working on Linux - Ubuntu

I have a test.cpp file located in tests folder:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include "../src/myFunctions.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test_1){

    myNamespace::someFunction("abc", 2);

}
```

myFunctions.h in src is defined like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
namespace myNamespace{

   void someFunction(std::string a, int b);

}
```

myFunctions.cpp which is in src also is defined like this:

```
#include "myFunctions.h"

namespace myNamespace{

   void myFunction(std::string a, int b){

     //does smth...
   }

}
```

Now I also have main.cpp in the same folder - src:

```
#include "myFunctions.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

   myNamespace::someFunction("a", 2);
   return 0;

}
```

so there are 2 folders src, tests. In tests there is test.cpp and in src these 3 other files.
Now when I run main.cpp everything works fine.
But when i run test.cpp as so when being in test cd:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

I get the following error:
undefined reference to 'myNamespace::someFunction( ...

So it doesn't know the function? why would it be?

If I run test.cpp after removing function call and i do smth like:
`BOOST_CHECK(10 == 12);`
then it works

Maybe:

Is there a way to run test.cpp from a function within myFunctions.cpp or main.cpp? Basically execute tests from file test/test.cpp but when I run main.cpp which uses myFunctions.cpp?

Comment: You need to compile and link all of the sources you use, so instead of `g++ test.cpp` you need `g++ test.cpp myFunctions.cpp`.

Comment: Ok, that's a problem. Is there a way to run test.cpp from a function within myFunctions.cpp or main.cpp? Basically execute tests from file test/test.cpp but when I run main.cpp which uses myFunctions.cpp?

Comment: @John_Cena Yes, declare the test function as `extern` in a header file which you include by both test.cpp and main.cpp. Then it can be called from main.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `someFunction` as `myFunction` in the implementation. Fixed with minimal working CMake ([download as zip](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/7a9587da-2ede-4820-a7df-80ae21668d51/demo.zip))

- File `CMakeLists.txt`

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
  project(sotest)

  add_subdirectory(src)
  add_subdirectory(tests)
  ```
- File `src/CMakeLists.txt`

  ```
  add_library(mylib OBJECT myFunctions.cpp)
  add_executable(main main.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(main mylib)
  ```
- File `src/main.cpp`

  ```
  #include "myFunctions.h"

  int main() {
      myNamespace::someFunction("a", 2);
  }
  ```
- File `src/myFunctions.cpp`

  ```
  #include "myFunctions.h"

  namespace myNamespace {
      void someFunction(std::string a, int b) {
          // does smth...
      }
  } // namespace myNamespace
  ```
- File `src/myFunctions.h`

  ```
  #pragma once
  #include <string>
  namespace myNamespace {
      void someFunction(std::string a, int b);
  }
  ```
- File `tests/CMakeLists.txt`

  ```
  add_executable(testrunner test.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(testrunner mylib)
  ```
- File `tests/test.cpp`

  ```
  #define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
  #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
  #include "../src/myFunctions.h"
  #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test_1) {
      myNamespace::someFunction("abc", 2);
      BOOST_CHECK(10 == 12);
  }
  ```

Which runs:

[image]

Comment: Added the live demo